# Error Message: You cannot/should not initialize the payer account as a program account

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

I have a program and when I run the tests using `anchor test` I keep getting the error that I cannot and shouldn't initialize the payer account as the program account.
Here is the rust code:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("CJXJk3KMD7LXXUAJRCZXEaZAN8feQrQ4VHe3jtSJoRHE");

#[program]
pub mod flipperapp {
use super::*;

pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
    let switch_account = &mut ctx.accounts.switch_account;
    switch_account.state = true;
    Ok(())
}

pub fn flip(ctx: Context<Flip>) -> Result<()> {
    let switch_account = &mut ctx.accounts.switch_account;
    if switch_account.state {
        switch_account.state =  false;
    } else {
        switch_account.state = true;
    }
    Ok(())
}
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
#[account(init, payer = user, space = 16 + 16)]
pub switch_account: Account<'info, SwitchAccount>,
#[account(mut)]
pub user: Signer<'info>,
pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Flip<'info> {
#[account(mut)]
pub switch_account: Account<'info, SwitchAccount>,
}
#[account]
pub struct SwitchAccount{
pub state: bool,
}
```

And here is the JS:

```
  const assert = require("assert");
  const { SystemProgram } = anchor.web3;

  describe("flipperapp", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
  const program = anchor.workspace.Flipperapp;

  it("Creates a flip account", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const SwitchAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    await program.methods.initialize().accounts({
      accounts: {
        switch_account: SwitchAccount.publicKey,
        user: provider,
        system_program: SystemProgram.programId
      },
      signers: [SwitchAccount]
    }).rpc();
    const baseAccount = await program.account.switch_account.fetch(switch_account.publicKey)
    assert.ok(baseAccount.state)
    _baseAccount = baseAccount;
  });
  it('Flip it', async () => {
    baseAccount = _baseAccount
    await program.rpc.flip({
      accounts: {
        switch_account: baseAccount.publicKey,
      }
    })

    const account = await program.account.switch_account.fetch(baseAccount.publicKey)
    assert.ok(account.state ==  false);

  })
  });
```

The error message I get after running the test is:
`Error: AnchorError thrown in programs/flipperapp/src/lib.rs:26. Error Code: TryingToInitPayerAsProgramAccount. Error Number: 4101. Error Message: You cannot/should not initialize the payer account as a program account.`

Please let me know what you think the issue with this code may be and why these errors keep getting thrown. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your test:

```
describe("flipperapp", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
  const program = anchor.workspace.Flipperapp;
  const wallet = anchor.workspace.Flipperapp.provider.wallet // <--- add this
```

Then update the accounts to camel case and try using wallet.provider :

```
    await program.methods.initialize().accounts({
      accounts: {
        switchAccount: SwitchAccount.publicKey,
        user: wallet.publickey, // <--- update this
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId
      },
      signers: [SwitchAccount]
    }).rpc();
```

Alternately, I think this would also work. Anchor automatically includes the provider wallet as a signer when using `.rpc`, and I believe Anchor can infer and include system program:

```
    await program.methods.initialize().accounts({
      accounts: {
        switchAccount: SwitchAccount.publicKey
      },
      signers: [SwitchAccount]
    }).rpc();
```

You can also update the second test to the `program.methods` format

Comment: i tried these but still keep getting the same errors